# Apache Camel Route is getting started automatically

Tags: java, apache-camel

Route loadfile is getting started automatically when I start main class.

On exception, when process should finish. It starts loadfile again and again.

It should get start from timer and then should call loadfile route, but loadfile is starting independent as well as from timer.

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(sr);
try {

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                onException(Exception.class)
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Extype:${exception.message}")
                        .stop();

                from("timer://alertstrigtimer?period=60s&repeatCount=1")
                        .startupOrder(1)
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "*******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: alertstrigtimer******************************")
                        .to("direct:loadFile").stop();

                from("direct:loadFile").routeId("loadfile")
                         .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "*******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: direct:loadFile******************************")
                         .from(getTriggerFileURI(getWorkFilePath(), getWorkFileName())).choice()

              .
              .
         });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(40000);
```

Following is log:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Type converters loaded (core: 194, classpath: 14)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: timer://alertstrigtimer?period=60s&repeatCount=1
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Skipping starting of route loadfile as its configured with autoStartup=false
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: loadDataAndAlerts started and consuming from: direct://loadDataAndAlerts
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 4 routes, of which 2 are started
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.761 seconds
[Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - timer://alertstrigtimer] INFO route1 - *******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: alertstrigtimer******************************
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - timer://alertstrigtimer] INFO loadfile - *******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: direct:loadFile******************************
[Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://null] INFO loadfile - *******************************Job-Alert-System: Started: direct:loadFile******************************
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be cause by this line `.from(getTriggerFileURI(getWorkFilePath(), getWorkFileName()))` in loadfile route. Route with multiple from endpoint is known as [Multiple Input](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/basicprinciples-multipleinputs) and this pattern is [removed in Camel 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452508/3759505).

*From [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/basicprinciples-multipleinputs),*

> > `from("URI1").from("URI2").from("URI3").to("DestinationUri");`
>
> ..., exchanges from each of the input endpoints,
> URI1, URI2, and URI3, are processed independently of each other and in
> separate threads. In fact, you can think of the preceding route as
> being equivalent to the following three separate routes:
>
> > `from("URI1").to("DestinationUri");`
> >
> > `from("URI2").to("DestinationUri");`
> >
> > `from("URI3").to("DestinationUri");`

Rather than using multiple from endpoint (extra independent input), try content enricher pattern ([pollEnrich](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html) for file component).