# How to fix several input per route in Camel 3.X.X?

Tags: apache-camel, migration, apache-camel-3

I have a route that looks like this:

```
from(URL_A)
  .from(URL_B)
  .to(URL_C)
  .process(...)
  // logging
  .to(URL_D)
```

This route works perfectly in Camel 2.X.X but not in 3.7.X

The error message I get:

> Only one input is allowed per route. Cannot accept input: From[direct:ABCD]

I checked the [migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html), but I cannot get how to migrate this sort of route.

Do you have any idea how to tackle it further?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate multiple from() dynamically Apache Camel RouteBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451201/generate-multiple-from-dynamically-apache-camel-routebuilder)

Comment: @ChinHuang It is a duplicate only if you know that you can use an array in `from` I obviously didn't know, so the question shouldn't be closed even it is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use direct component: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/direct-component.html

For example:

```
from(URL_A)
  .to(direct:collector)
from(URL_B)
  .to(direct:collector)
  
from(direct:collector)
  .to(URL_C)
  .process(...)
  // logging
  .to(URL_D)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Stepan Shcherbakov suggested a solution, below will be an enhancement of it:

```
String [] sources = {URL_A, URL_B}
for (String source : sources) {
  from(source)
    .to(direct:collector)
}

from(direct:collector)
  .to(URL_C)
  .process(...)
  // logging
  .to(URL_D)
```

Comment: You can also use the seda component instead of direct. This will make the whole solution more responsive.